# Strange song played on restart

Tags: boot, noise

This kind of freaked me out. I wa shutting down on ubuntu 19.10 and as my computer was almost off (screen had turned off, but fan and keyboard backlight was still on) it played a strange like 8 bit song, maybe 6-7 notes before turning off. Kinda sounded like those bios beeps, but arranged into a song.

It's a t480s with just ubuntu on it. I don't know seemed, strange thought someone here might know what it was.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2rzkO3jwko  Might be diagnostics smartbeeps that Lenovo does.

Comment: @Terrance Interesting, that's both very new age-y and also not at the same time

Comment: @Terrance Yep, that's it. Thanks!